# How to account for NFL divisions for predicting playoff chances?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic

I'm trying to run logistic regression to find whether or not a team will make the playoffs based on their previous year stats, player awards, W-L record, etc. In the NFL, there are 2 conferences and 4 divisions within each conference. Every division winner makes the playoffs, plus 3 wildcard teams (the 3 wildcard teams are the 3 teams with the best record from the remaining non-division winners). This makes 7 teams making the playoffs from each Conference. The problem is, I do not know how to account for this in a logistic regression model. Theoretically, my model could predict 10 teams making the playoffs from one conference, and only 4 teams from the second conference, even though that is not possible. Does anyone know how I could go about accounting for these variables?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your own post.

Answer (score 0):

"The problem is, I do not know how to account for this in a logistic regression model."

Interesting idea. Can you provide more information here? Specifically, how you are coding your outcome variables. The logistic regression model can only predict what you operationalize as your dependent variable. So if you have a multinomial model, which is what I'm assuming you have, the outcome, whether 10 or 4 teams, can only be whatever you code it as.